# What to do if OP edits their question from a different account?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In the edit review queue, I sometimes encounter edits by someone who writes as if they were the OP, or even claim to be the OP, even though they are using a different account.

The OP account is almost always low rep and on the form "userNNNN", and the user making the edit is usually a new account as well. Sometimes, both accounts even have the same name even though they are different accounts. It can't be proven, but presumably both accounts are for the same person.

The edit is usually some kind of clarification of a type that would not be OK for a random user to make, but perfectly reasonable for OP to make in response to a comment.

How do I deal with these?

- Accept?
- Reject as "clearly contradicts authors intent"?
- Flag for moderator attention?
- Something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If in any doubt flag for a mod - we can check if they are from the same person pretty accurately.

But if it is a simple clarification and the edit makes sense, I'd suggest approving.